# Kubernetes: How to implement a Network ResourceQuota

Tags: kubernetes, quota

I'm familiar with the [Kubernetes quotas for CPU and memory usage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/). However, I'm envisaging a scenario in which certain containers are guaranteed to use *a lot* of network bandwidth, and I can't see any way of warning Kubernetes of this. (e.g. don't put two on the same machine, don't put too much else on this machine even if the other quotas are fine). How can I effect this sort of behaviour? For the purposes of the question I have full control of the cluster and am prepared to write code if necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to apply [Support traffic shaping](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#support-traffic-shaping) using `kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth` and `kubernetes.io/egress-bandwidth annotations`. It can only be applied to your PODS.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth: 1M
    kubernetes.io/egress-bandwidth: 1M
..
```

Also official k8s documentation gives link to [bandwidth plugin](https://www.cni.dev/plugins/current/meta/bandwidth/). Try to apply in for your needs.

And read [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2856).